# Detach Disk from GCE VM to mount and edit SSH

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

i am trying to detach disk on temp instance so i can mount and edit ssh_config but when i am using `gcloud compute instances detach-disk INSTANCE --disk mydisk` it shows

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.detach-disk) There was a problem fetching the resource:
 - Insufficient Permission
```

any suggestion? i'm new to google Cloud

Answer (score 0):

First, you should run [`gcloud auth login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) to authenticate with Google Cloud Platform.

Also, you probably want to add `--zone ZONE` and `--project PROJECT` flags to your command line.

To avoid setting the project and zone every time with `gcloud`, you can set defaults for either or both of these:

- Run [`gcloud config set project MY-PROJECT`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) to set the default project
- Run [`gcloud config set compute/zone MY-ZONE`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) to set the default zone